# How to show UIDatePIcker over the TabBar like keyboard did

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uidatepicker

I Know there is few question on this site talk about this... but I don't find real answer that i can use...

I have a form that contain common `UITextField` and a `UIButton` that supposedly show `UIDatePicker` sliding from bottom when user click the button...

The main question is:

- how to show `UIDatePicker` over the TabBar like iphone keyboard did
- how make the `UIDatePicker` is behave like a keyboard, so when i click UITextField while 
  selecting date, it changed to keyboard and vice versa... like iphone contact did.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set input View of your textfield to be a UIDatePicker object:
UITextField has following properties.
@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView;

Use following code:

```
yourTextfield.inputView = yourDatePicker;
```

so instead of keyboard which is default for UITextfield, your picker will appear when textfield is tapped....

Comment: oh yeah... I see... My mistake if I try to implement it by myself using button to show the DatePicker... Accepted

Answer (score 0):

five years ago question.

1.create a subclass of the UIResponder class

2.redeclare inputview as read-write

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIView *inputView;
```

3.set canBecomeFirstResponder to YES

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
return YES;
}
```

4.set inputview such as datepicker

```
self.inputView = self.datePicker;
```

5.set UIResponder to firstResponder when you want

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

5.you can see datepicker show like keyboard